# C Bitwise Operation Question

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Can someone help me understand whats going on with this code. It looks like it is making an integer from an array of bits. Im not sure how its doing that. Why is there a bitwise & operation on OxFF? Inst this just going to produce the same result?

```
//first take the first  4 bytes read out of the socket into an array and
//make them a 32 bit integer

        long ltemp =0;
        long ltemp2 = 0;
        ltemp  = ltemp | (unsigned char)(analog_val_ptr[0] & 0xff);
        ltemp  = ltemp << 24;
        ltemp2 = ltemp2 | (unsigned char)(analog_val_ptr[1] & 0xff);
        ltemp2 = ltemp2 << 16;
        ltemp = ltemp2 | ltemp;
        ltemp2 =0;
        ltemp2 = ltemp2 | (unsigned char)(analog_val_ptr[2] & 0xff);
        ltemp2 = ltemp2 << 8;
        ltemp = ltemp2 | ltemp;
        ltemp  =  ltemp | (unsigned char)(analog_val_ptr[3] & 0xff);

///then convert that integer into a float, passing
```

Comment: What is the type of analog_val_ptr? It does look like the programmer is trying to be doubly sure by using `&0xFF` and casting to `unsigned char`. Either would do on it's own I think.

Comment: its a byte, the data is coming in from a socket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a *very* long-winded way of just converting four 8-bit bytes into a 32-bit long.

The `and`ing with `0xff` is just ensuring that only the lower 8 bits of each value are used (`0xff == binary 11111111`).

The bit-shifting (in multiples of 8) is just to get each character into the right position.

The whole thing could be replaced with something like:

```
unsigned long ltemp  = (unsigned char)(analog_val_ptr[0] & 0xff);
ltemp = (ltemp << 8) | (unsigned char)(analog_val_ptr[1] & 0xff);
ltemp = (ltemp << 8) | (unsigned char)(analog_val_ptr[2] & 0xff);
ltemp = (ltemp << 8) | (unsigned char)(analog_val_ptr[3] & 0xff);
```

Or, alternatively (and assuming they're available), use the correct tools for the job, specifically `htonl()` and `ntohl()`.

Comment: The `&0xff` and cast to `unsigned char` are completely redundant. One or the other should be removed, probably the cast.

Comment: As a matter of style, it might be good to make the result a `unsigned long`, just to be definite about the outcome.

Comment: @R, I'm allowing for the possibility that `char` may be more than 8 bits :-) No, actually, you're probably correct but, since I said "something _like_ ...", I'll leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's building an integer from an array of *bytes*. It may be that `analog_val_ptr[]` is an array of `int` or `short` values, and this code is designed to treat each entry as a byte. The masking is to prevent the sign bit from flooding the destination variable.

Answer (score 1):

looks like it is going for an endian independent conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
var = 0x ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
         & & & & & & & & 
      0x 0 0 0 0 0 0 f f 
      ------------------
         0 0 0 0 0 0 ? ?
```

After the AND operation the lower 8 bits will be found with `var & 0xff`. Its a way to only cut out the needed portion, masking.

The code above simply pastes the lower bytes of 4 array elements into the variable `ltemp` as a long int.